# Bad syntax for an iteration

Tags: multithreading, angular, loops, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to create a loop in order to iterate my variable threads :
 `threads: Subject<{[key: string]: Thread }> = new BehaviorSubject({});`

By trying this, I do not get what I want. Indeed my variable `threadDictionary [key]` returns me false instead of returning a Thread object to me.

```
var threadDictionary = this.threads.asObservable().map((threadDictionary: {[key: string]: Thread}) => {
  return threadDictionary;
});

for( let key in threadDictionary ) {
  console.log("threadDictionary", threadDictionary);
  console.log("threadDictionary[key]", threadDictionary[key]);

  if(threadDictionary[key].participants[0].name.startsWith(str)) {
    return threadDictionary[key];
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help...

//////EDIT

```
searchArrayThreads: { [key: string]: Thread; }[];

searchThreads: Subject<{ [key: string]: Thread; }[]> =
new BehaviorSubject<{ [key: string]: Thread; }[]>(new Array<{ [key: string]: Thread; }>());

threadTest: Subject<Array<Thread>> = new Subject()

searchUser(): void {
  this.searchArrayThreads = [];
  let str;
  let element = document.getElementById('chat-window-input');

  if(element != null) {
    str = (element as HTMLInputElement).value;
  }
  else {
    str = null;
  }

  this.threadTest.next((<any>Object).values(this.threads.getValue()));

  const check = (threadDictionary) => {
    for (let key in threadDictionary) {
      const thread = threadDictionary[key];
      if(thread.participants[0].name.startsWith(str)) {
        return thread;
      }
    }
  };

  this.threadTest.subscribe(newThreads => {
    const r = check(newThreads);
    console.log('newThreads', newThreads);
     if (r) {
      this.searchArrayThreads.push(r);
      this.searchThreads.next(this.searchArrayThreads);
    }
    if(r) {
      console.log('found !', r);
    } else {
      console.log('not found');
    }
  });
}
```

When I try, it does not work. I get the impression that my threadTest variable contains nothing.
I add my previous threads variable to the new threadTest variable like this :

```
this.threadTest.next((<any>Object).values(this.threads.getValue()));
```

Here is the function I had before to subscribe to the stream :

```
displaySearchUser(): void {
  this.searchUser().subscribe((thread: Thread) => {
    if (thread !== undefined) {
      this.searchArrayThreads.push(thread);
    }
    this.searchThreads.next(this.searchArrayThreads);
  });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop For on a BehaviorSubject stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038790/loop-for-on-a-behaviorsubject-stream)

Comment: @MarkvanStraten
Sure enough my question looks it, but it is not exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi :) I think there might be some confusion about the concept of Subject.

From https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/subject.md :

> What is a Subject? An RxJS Subject is a special type of Observable that allows values to be multicasted to many Observers. While plain Observables are unicast (each subscribed Observer owns an independent execution of the Observable), Subjects are multicast.

Knowing this, and this:

> Every Subject is an Observable.

you need to subscribe to it in order to get any changes (and values) from the observable. It should be something like this:

```
const check = (ths) => {
  for (let i in ths) {
    const thread = ths[i];
    if (thread.participants[0].name.startsWith(str)) {
      return thread;
    }
  }
};

threads.subscribe(newThreads => {
  const r = check(newThreads);
  if (r) {
    console.log('found !', r);
  }else {
    console.log('not found :(');
  }
});
```

And your threads variable should look like this:

```
threads: Subject<Array<Thread>> = new Subject();
```

One more thing, i think you should use just Subject and not BehaviorSubject because it will emit an empty one at the beginning (unless you want to emit an initial value at the beginning).

This whole example is in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uLrgsr32/

Comment: Yes I am a beginner ..
Thank you very much for your help but I'm not sure I understand. I published my post. Should we do this? Because there are errors ...

Comment: I do not understand why I can not add anything to the variable threads. When I test onNext, it puts me an error.

Comment: The Subject is a class that is Observer and Observable at the same time. It handles **data stream**. So the subject is not an array, you cannot directly obtain the data form it; you gotta subscribe in order to get the data. `ths` is the name of the parameter in the check function, and is the new incomming array of threads. You cannot use `onNext` because it is strictly for Subject, you use just `next` when using BehaviourSubject.