# Communication between two Subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a variable threads:

```
threads: Subject<{[key: string]: Thread }> = new BehaviorSubject({});
```

I want to add this threads variable to my new threadTest variable:

```
threadTest : Subject<Array<Thread>> = new Subject();
```

Is it possible, like :

```
this.threadTest = this.threads;
```

Thanks for your help ...

Comment: No. Because `threads` has another type than `threadTest`. If both were from the same type, it would work.

Comment: `this.threadTest.next(this.threads.getValue());` @D.Simon is this will not work?

Comment: @marouanekadiri
It puts this error : Property 'getValue' does not exist on type 'Subject<{ [key: string]: Thread; }>'

Comment: Change the type `Subject<..` to `BehaviorSubject<..`

Comment: @Floriane those it work this time?

Comment: There is a flatMap in observables. I think it convert multiple observables to single the way you want. Not sure , you can explore

Comment: @marouanekadiri
I need to change for threads variable or threadTest variable ?

Comment: only for the treads variable because the getValue function exist only in the BehaviorSubject not in Subject

Comment: @marouanekadiri
It does not work either
`Argument of type '{ [key: string]: Thread; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Thread[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: Thread; }'.`

Comment: To cast your associative list try using `(<any>Object).values(yourObject)` like this `this.threadTest.next((<any>Object).values(this.threads.getValue()));`

Comment: @Floriane Try instead of `this.threadTest.next(this.threads.getValue());` this `this.threadTest.next((<any>Object).values(this.threads.getVa‌​lue()));`

Comment: @marouanekadiri
Thank you I think it works. However, this does not solve my global problem that I posed on this question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049922/bad-syntax-for-an-iteration)
I'm sorry I'm a little desperate

Comment: @marouanekadiri
Did you see the link for the chat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy values from a BehaviorSubject to another Subject, You need to use this
`this.threadTest.next(this.threads.getValue());`(as an exemple)

But in this case, If you use simply this code you will face a problem of type `{[key:string]:Thread}` doesn't match with the `Thread[]` to solve this you need to transform it to an array like this : `this.threadTest.next((<any>Object).values(this.threads.getVa‌​‌​lue()));`